# Create list of lists in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

How do I create a list of lists?

I have a mutable list of ints:

```
val rsrpList = mutableListOf<Int>()
```

Now I am trying to create a list of lists, like this:

```
val rsrpList = mutableListOf<Int>()
val rsrqList = mutableListOf<Int>()
val levelList = mutableListOf<Int>()

val listoflists = List<List<Int>>
listoflists.add(rsrpList)
listoflists.add(rsrqList)
listoflists.add(levelList)
```

but I know this is wrong, because I'm adding a list one at a time, instead of a list of lists. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is fine (you have an empty list, you're adding lists to that list, you end up with a list of lists!) but if you're trying to avoid mutability by declaring everything at once:

```
val listOfLists = listOf(rsrpList, rsrqList, levelList)
```

and you can declare those lists at the same time if you want

```
val listOfLists = listOf(
    listOf(1, 2, 3),
    listOf(9, 8, 7),
    listOf(7, 7, 7)
)
```

or you can use `mutableListOf` if you need any of them to be mutable! The formatting there isn't necessary, I just think it looks clearer how they're nested

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with the Kotlin Standard Library. Both `List` and `MutableList` can be created to a specific size (3 in this case) and specify a lambda that will initialize each value.

```
val listOfList = MutableList(3) { mutableListOf<Int>() }
```

Or:

```
val listOfList = List(3) { mutableListOf<Int>() }
```

**Update:** To initialize a List with precreated lists:

```
val listOfList = listOf(list1, list2, list3)
```

Or in your specific case:

```
val listOfList = listOf(rsrpList, rsrqList, levelList)
```

And in both cases you can replace `listOf` with `mutableListOf` if you want a mutable list as the main type.

Comment: Thanks! It works. What is the right syntax for initializing with my lists I created?